# unable to get customer data from session in custom module?

Tags: magento-1.9, session, zend-framework, customer-session

I am developing custom module which needs to use customer data from session. Here I am having some problem with session. I am unable to get any customer data in my custom module from session even if the user logged in.

I logged below code in my index controller.

```
Mage::getSingleton('core/session', array('name' => 'frontend'));
        $customer_id = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer()->getId();
        Mage::log("Index - customer id check: " . $customer_id);
```

A failure to get customer Id.

After that added customer_login event and tried to log the same in the observer method. Here it worked.

But, still not working in the index controller.

Please help

Answer (score 10):

You need to check  customer is `loggedin or not`.

Without `customer loggin`,you cannot get `customer data from session`:

```
if (Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn()):
    $customer = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer();
    $customer->getEmail();
    $customer->getFirstname();
    $customer->getLastname();
    $customer->getId();
endif;
```

Comment: Thanks Amit, I checked with your code, but still I am not getting the customer details in my custom module index controller.

Comment: Are controllers work?

Answer (score 3):

Try below code

```
    if (Mage::getModel('customer/session')->isLoggedIn()) {
        $customer = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer();
        echo '<pre>';
        print_r($customer->getData());
    } else {
        echo 'Not Logged in';
    }
```